# How can I extend a static final guava utilities class?

Tags: java, inheritance, guava

When I've used common-collections I've done custom extensions to those utils like:

```
class MyCollectionUtils extends CollectionsUtils {
static myutilityMethod()
static removeDublicate(..)
static myPredicate(...)
}
```

In that case I have all functionality from `CollectionsUtils` and my extension methods with only one import!

In guava all static utilities classes are `final`.

What is the best approach to extend the guava collection API? For example, new common used predicate, collection factory etc, collection combiner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one *why* answer, readability.  The reader now needs to know all about your utility class, even for methods which just forward to Guava.

```
ArrayList<String> myStrings = MySpecialLists.newArrayList();
```

Is that a standard ArrayList or a special list I've initialized with default values?  Even if I know Guava inside and out, I can't know the answer until I've examined your API.  And client code can't guarantee that it will remain the simple Guava version (perhaps you'll stop inheriting from Guava, and just implement all the list methods yourself).

Answer (score 4):

Since all of the methods are static, extending the utility class doesn't really offer any value other than the ability to get everything with one import.

It would seem easiest to me just to create your own utility class that doesn't extend the Guava one and just import the guava one when you need it (with an extra import statement). Having multiple import statements isn't bad; with any competent IDE you hardly even have to manage them yourself.

*If you really want to, the utility class that you write could wrap the guava methods, but that would just create more in the way of maintenance, since you'd have to update your methods when the guava ones change.*

Comment: I do not agree that it is bad idea to extends static class with static class. In Scala for example it is very common to extends one Object(singleton) with another.
If I do it your way I will have to always do two imports "import static guava.*, import static myutils.*"

Comment: @yura yes, but imports work differently in Scala. In Java, it's just plain ugly.

Comment: I didn't say it was a "bad idea", I simply said it doesn't offer value. If the designer of the API declared it `final`, it was their intention to not have it extended (for whatever reason). I guess I still don't see what's wrong with a couple more `import` statements. You hardly even have to manage them yourself if you're using an IDE.

Comment: @Rob The problem is that it doubles imports and what are behind them(which methods in guava and which in my extension). It is common to have special for project(big one) PredicateUtils, StringUtils, CollectionsUtils(in my case optimizied dedublication methods), some iterables utils. So instead of importing 5 utils I have to import 10. And also I have to remember all names, and thats even worse to hold additionally 20 classes in memory.

Comment: @yura - But imports are so trivial. All you have to do (in Eclipse) is Ctrl+Shift+O on the type and it will put the import there for you.

Comment: Extending a class is for inheritance, which is not possible with all static methods.  You are trying to use it for aggregation to simply give you a single import statement.  This is also prone to easy to make errors like method hiding.  In addition, it is much more clear to the user of a static method what they are using and finding appropriate documentation when they realize it is Guava vs. a home rolled solution.  Static utility classes are often made final and/or have private constructors, both of which have the effect of making them un-extendable.

Answer (score 3):

We designed these static utility classes specifically to prevent them from being extended.

For starters, you couldn't extend the static utility classes even if they weren't final, because they don't expose constructors.  (You'd get a compiler error that the default constructor couldn't be used.)

Imports are cheap.  Go ahead and use two.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should use inheritance in your example about static utilities anyway. Extending classes should be reserved for when you actually need to model some type of parent-child relationship. The number of imports is not a good enough reason to abandon good style.